# Different Viewport, Different Textures...?

Tags: rendering, mesh, texturing, materials

Hope you're doing well :>!

Ran into a different problem in Blender, this one has me quite confused (less so than the geometry one, that one was just lacking experience lol).

For the model I'm making, whenever I swap between the solid viewport shading and material viewport shading, really weird things happen. It's easier to show that explain:

[image: Material Preview Mode Viewport Angle 1]

[image: Solid Shading Viewport Angle 1]

[image: Material Preview Mode Viewport Angle 2]

[image: Solid Shading Viewport Angle 2]

The ear texture kind of inverts, part of the geometry just goes transparent, and whenever I combine my textures (These are before that) this just becomes the default no matter what viewport I'm on.

No idea what to do, I've done shifting of textures and all, to no avail, and I'm stumped. Any and all help will be appreciated !

Comment: Maybe not all faces normals are pointing in the right direction. In Edit mode select all > recalculate or enable Viewport overlays > Face Orientation and make them all blue. Other than that not sure it's clear what the question is

Comment: that fixed the problem, recalculating the normals! thanks a ton, didn't think that that would help with this type of problem!